# Use Django's pre_fetch_related function

Tags: django, django-queryset

Given the following scenario:

In a library, a book can be placed in only 1 sleeve. Over the course, the book could be moved from sleeve to sleeve.

And the models

```
class Sleeve(models.Model):
  sleeve_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  sleeve_number = models.DecimalField()

class Book(models.Model):
  book_title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  sits_in_sleeve = models.ForeignKey(Sleeve, null=False)
```

Now I would like to create a Django Queryset to query all the Sleeves with a number between 1 and 10, and query all the books titles belonging to that. How do I do so with `prefetch_related`?

In other words, I can do something like:

```
sleeves = Sleeve.objects.filter(sleeve_number__lte=10,sleeve_number__gte=1)
for s in sleeves:
  b = Book.objects.get(sits_in_sleeve=s)
  s.book = b
```

But is there a more elegant way to do so?

Comment: Do you actually need the sleeves at all or are you only interested in the books?

Comment: **and query all the books titles belonging to that** As far as I can understand, you need all the books between sleeve_number 1 to 10. Right..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
b = Book.objects.filter(sits_in_sleeve__sleeve_number__lte=10,sits_in_sleeve__sleeve_number__gte=1)
```

Because Book model has a field named **sits_in_sleeve** which has a foreign key relationship with Sleeve model.

So you can perform any operation on fields of Sleeve model by adding double underscore i.e. ( __ ) to fetch the fields of related Sleeve model.

**UPDATE:**

As Sayse suggested,  you can also use range function instead of the separate use of __gte and __lte.
Like this:

```
b = Book.objects.filter(sits_in_sleeve__sleeve_number__range=(1,10))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what the op actually needs but was waiting for a response... you may want to use [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range)  - `sits_in_sleeve__sleeve_number__range=(1,10)`

Comment: @Sayse Yeah, this is a better way to approach the less than 10, greater than 1 condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **prefetch_related**:

```
sleeves = Sleeve.objects.filter(sleeve_number__lte=10,sleeve_number__gte=1).prefetch_related('book_set')
```

You can then get the books for each sleeve without making additional queries:

```
for sleeve in sleeves:
    books = sleeve.book_set.all()
```

Comment: hey! my question to you would be: how does the parameter `book_set` come from? I have seen this implementation but am not sure if it can be applied to all and that's why I'm asking. Thank you :)

Comment: Appending `_set` to the lowercased model name is the default `related_name`. You can override this in the field definition of the `ForeignKey` field with the `related_name` argument. `sleeve.book_set` is then the so-called related manager that provides you with the model manager functionality for all the books of one sleeve.